# Media chase vs. aspdotnetstorefront

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, aspdotnetstorefront

I'm starting an ecommerce project that has very heavy backend integration requirements. I need an ecommerce package that is easy to customize and can function at the enterprise level. If you are familiar with Media Chase and Aspdotnetstorefront, could you let me know what your experience has been and if you lean towards one or the other (or if you recommend a total different platform).  Has to be .net.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I represent AspDotNetStorefront and we've built thousands of Web sites with dozens of third-party back-end integrations.

If you let me know what kind of integration you're looking to do, I can put you in touch with someone in our authorized developer network to hear about their experience developing for the platform.

We also have a strong community in our forums: http://forums.aspdotnetstorefront.com

I'm sure they'd be willing to relate their personal experiences with the specific kind of development you're looking to do as well.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in need of a .net based enterprise level ecommerce platform I would recommend Microsoft Commerce Server. It is a highly customizable platform, rich in features, and it has many options for back end integration as it uses web services for communication with the back end. If you choose you could also use BizTalk as middleware, and you could then leverage the built-in adapters for commerce server, as well as the adapters for many other systems (ERP, warehouse, etc).